# Convergent sequences definition problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

Let $q$ be a fixed rational number. Then $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of rational numbers which does not converge to $q$ if there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that there exists a single value of $N>0$ and at least one value of $n>N$ such that $|q_n-q|>\epsilon$.

Question: Is this true or false? How can I think of it? Would you like to give me some examples?

Comment: I am not sure about your "there exists a single value of $N>0$"

Comment: Having at least one $n>N$ such that $|q_n-q|>\epsilon$ is not enough for the sequence to not converge. It may happen that there are only finitely such values of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of convergence is: $(q_n)_n$ converges to $q$ if and only if:
\begin{align*}
\forall \epsilon \!>\!0~ \exists N\!\in\! \mathbb{N}~\forall n\!\geq\! N: |q_n-q|< \epsilon
\end{align*}
So the negation of that is:
\begin{align*}
\exists \epsilon \!>\!0~ \forall N\!\in\! \mathbb{N}~\exists n\!\geq\! N: |q_n-q|\geq \epsilon
\end{align*}
which translates into: There is an $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $n\geq N$ such that $|q_n-q| \geq \epsilon$.

I hope that helps :)